# Using async and findOne for mongoDB takes decades to connect

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, mongodb, async-await

I want to use the async to verify whether the user is registered so it can access the app when the user tries to log in. This code doesn't give any error, but it takes decades to search from the database, and in the end, I've never seen it connected.

Any suggestion to fix this and make it faster? I think I'm mistaken in the code I wrote because something ain't right.

```
const usersCollection = require('../db').collection("users");

User.prototype.login = () =>{
async function run() {
    try {
        const attemptedUser = await usersCollection.findOne({ name: this.data.username });
        if (attemptedUser && attemptedUser.password == this.data.password) {
            console.log("congrats");
        } else if (attemptedUser && attemptedUser.password !== this.data.password) {
            throw new Error("Access Denied");
        }
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err.message);
    }
}}
```

Comment: how are you making the connection to the db? Aloso, how are you defining this.data.username?

Comment: I make connection using async in db file so it first connects to db with the connection string then if all the validations okay in the database, the app starts. All of this takes milliseconds.

I have a constructor function for "data" in my user model and I use it for other functions with the help of the router, like user registration, user controller etc, it works well.

Comment: and you are exporting the connection from the db file right? sorry for this questions but I'm just trying to figure out which is the state of your app before giving any answer

Comment: also, is this mongoose or the mongodb native driver?

Comment: No worries, thanks for helping me. Yes exactly, I export it. I use mongodb native, not mongoose.

Comment: well, the way you are doing the query is correct; if what you are importing from the db file it's the db connection itself it should work without problem. Does any console.log output anything to your terminal?